# Doesnt $E=mc^2$ contradict the preservation of charge?

Tags: particle-physics, charge, conservation-laws, mass-energy, antimatter

If we say that any mass is the same as a given energy amount, so we in theory could turn any particle into energy, wouldn't that mean we could turn a proton or electron into energy without turning its counterpart into energy and therefore break the rule of preservation of charge?

The currently known way to turn a particle into energy is to create an antiparticle and ram them together, which means that when they turn into energy, preservation of charge is still intact, but in theory, if we could turn single particles into energy wouldn't it break the law?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Cleaning Up the Misconceptions

---

#### $1.$ There is No "Turning a Particle Into Energy"

There is no meaning that can be attached to the phrase "turn a particle into energy". Energy is not some kind of a supernatural spirit of its own that can float around without a physical conduit. Energy is simply a specific measurable property of systems. There is no energy on its own, you have the energy *of an electron*, the energy *of a proton*, the energy *of an electromagnetic wave*, etc. An analogy would be the names of people. There is no name on its own, there are only names *of people*.

#### $2.$ There is No "Turning Mass Into Energy" Either

Furthermore, $E=mc^2$ doesn't imply that mass can be converted to energy either. Mass is also a measurable property of systems, just like its energy. You can transform one system into another, you can't turn one property of a system into another property of a system (or that of another system). It would be like saying converting the price of a pen into its color. It's a meaningless thing to say. What $E=mc^2$ says, when you write it correctly as $E_0=mc^2$, is that there exists a relation between two properties of a system. Namely that the rest energy of a system (the "rest" is what the $_0$ in $E_0$ stands for) is equal to its mass (times $c^2$).

##### Why Do People Say These Things Then?

$1$. The process you have in mind is the conversion of charged matter particles into uncharged photons. Since photons are not matter particles, I understand how they can be tempting to visualize as ethereal lumps of pure energy. However, that's not correct for the reasons described above.

$2$. The reason people say that $E=mc^2$ (again, the correct version is $E_0=mc^2$) implies that mass can be converted to energy is that people try to mesh together two inconsistent pictures of the world and the only way to resolve the clash between two inconsistent pictures of the world is to accept an absurd statement as correct. In particular, in Newtonian mechanics, the mass of a composite system is equal to the sum of the masses of its components. In relativistic mechanics, this is no longer true. The reason is that mass of a system is the square root of the scalar product of the four-momentum of the system with itself. Since the four-momentum of a composite system *is* equal to the sum of the four-momenta of the constituents of the system, the mass of the composite system cannot be obtained by simply adding the masses of the constituents ($\sqrt{(\vec{a}+\vec{b})^2}\neq \vert \vec{a}\vert+\vert\vec{b}\vert$). However, people still want to hold on to the notion that masses can be added up linearly to obtain the total mass of a system. Thus, they attribute the difference between $\sqrt{(\vec{a}+\vec{b})^2}$ and $\vert \vec{a}\vert+\vert\vec{b}\vert$ to "the mass that is converted to energy according to $E=mc^2$". This is not a bad way to talk if everyone involved in the conversation understands that we are talking in shorthand and it shouldn't be taken literally.

---

### Answering the Question

Finally, coming to your question. Can charged particles of a non-zero total charge be converted to a bunch of uncharged photons? The answer is simply no because what it means to say that the conservation of electric charges is a law of nature is to say that the laws of interactions in the standard model of particle physics are such that there is no interaction that allows a bunch of particles to be transformed into another bunch of particles in such a way that the total electric charge is different at the end of the process. I would like to add two points that might help you clear up the issue in your mind a bit more:

- It is to be emphasized that the physics that lies behind the conversion of an electron and a positron into a photon has nothing specific to do with $E_0=mc^2$, it's the fact that the Lagrangian of quantum electrodynamics includes an interaction term between the electron field and the photon field. Yes, $E_0=mc^2$ would hold for every system in physics, including the electrons and the positrons at the beginning of the process and the photons at the end of the process. However, it describes kinematics, not dynamics.
- Furthermore, the way to look at the laws of physics is to NOT think along the following lines: "if a process is allowed by law X but is not allowed by law Y then does it mean that using law X, we can violate law Y?" Only if law X required something to exist that is not allowed by law Y then they would be in contradiction and something would have to give. There does hold a kind of totalitarian principle in physics which says that whatever is not forbidden, must happen. However, here, "forbidden" means "forbidden by any of the laws". In other words, if any of the laws forbid something then it means that it won't happen. Only if all the laws allow something but we still don't see it then it's something to be really curious about.

Answer (score 3):

You can't turn a particle 'into energy'. A particle *is* energy. You can change particles into other types of particles, i.e. you can change one form energy into other forms of energy. The reaction you describe is turning a matter-antimatter pair into photons/other particles. These reactions follow strict rules and conservation of charge is one of them. So no, it does not violate conservation of charge.

Answer (score 2):

In principle, if you want to change a single particle into energy, you need to specify the interaction that allows that. This interaction would be (by definition if it turns a charge carrying particle into some other particle like the photon, that is not charged, and no further particles) be a theory that violates charge conservation.
So far, we have not found an interaction that violates charge conservation, so the answer to your question is no, we cannot just take a particle and turn it into energy.

Keep in mind that the mass energy equivalence relates the two observables mass and energy, but it does not tell you about other rules that come on top of it, like the fact that interactions have to obey the conservation of momentum or charge.

Answer (score 0):

The rule is you can do anything not forbidden by at least one consideration. Just as some processes are forbidden by energy conservation in the light of $E=mc^2$, some processes that issue alone doesn't prevent are instead forbidden by charge conservation.